# Why won't my bash script exit after execution?

Tags: bash, exit

I compiled a short bash one-liner to focus a running application or launch it if it isn't running:

```
#!/bin/bash
#intellilaunch.sh

wmctrl -a $1 || $1 & disown
exit 1
```

The command exits perfectly fine when run directly from the command line:

```
:~$ wmctrl -a firefox || firefox & disown
[1] 32505
```

A quick check with the system monitor shows that only firefox is running.

However, when I launch firefox via the script (`./intellilaunch.sh firefox`) it spawns a persisting new process called `intellilaunch.sh firefox`, which only exits after closing firefox.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

I modified my script according to michas' suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

program=$(basename $1)

if ! wmctrl -a "$program"; then
  "$1"&
fi
```

Not a one-liner anymore but it works perfectly fine now!

Comment: does it work with another program? Eg.: `xclock`?

Comment: @jippie Same exact behaviour: script launches xclock but then stays open instead of exiting; only exits after I close xclock

Comment: Strange, I copied your script and works fine here. Only difference is that I didn't use an `exit 1`

Comment: I just tried it out without `exit 1`. Same result. How did you launch the script? Did you use `./intellilaunch.sh xclock` or something else?

Comment: yup. What OS / distribution are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with LXDE/Openbox, you?

Comment: (k)ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this behavior on my system. From your description is sounds like there is a process not properly set to background.

Try to run as `bash -x intellilaunch.sh xclock`, this should show, what is going on.

Also `||` binds stronger than `&`, therefore you send the whole pipe in background. Maybe an explicit `if` would be a good idea.

Your

```
wmctrl -a firefox || firefox & disown ; exit 1
```

is interpreted as

```
( wmctrl -a firefox || firefox ) & disown ; exit 1
```

whereas you probably meant

```
wmctrl -a firefox || ( firefox & disown ) ; exit 1
```

Beause of that, bash will start two jobs one with wmctl and firefox - and another one with disown and exit. As the background job needs a short time to launch it will probably start the commands slighly later, that is why the output of `bash -x` seems to be in the wrong order.

Comment: Do you really need the `disown`? Does your script show the same blocking behavior without the `disown`?

Comment: `bash -x intellilaunch.sh xclock` displayed the same behaviour, i.e. the process just wouldn't exit (the `disown` was superfluous, I think). I followed your suggestion and dropped the `||` for an `if` statement (see above). Everything  works perfectly fine now. Thank you!

Comment: That still leaves the question why it did not work before. - Running bash with -x lets bash print out all the executed commands. What was the output in your case? - Did just leaving out the `disown` change the situation?

Comment: I pasted the outputs both with and without `disown` [here](http://pastebin.com/eVesD10X). Look as if everything is out of order. Is it due to the `||`?

Comment: No, it's because of the `&`. (See extended answer.)

Comment: That makes sense. Learned something new today, thank you!